# How do I maintain the current map extent of a project file on save in QGIS2?

Tags: mac, qgis-2

I'm using QGIS 2.0.1 on a Mac and having an issue with maintaining the map extent after saving the project.  I save my project file with a certain extent and when I re-open the file the map is centered on 0,0.  I can use the "Zoom Last" button to get back to the extent of the map when I saved.  This occurs regardless of how `Enable 'on the fly' CRS transformation` is set.  Layer order, symbol changes, etc are all maintained on save, only the extent jumps to 0,0.  My test shapefile is in WGS84.

Looking at the project file XML I see the correct extent coordinates in the `<extent>` tags.  So it looks like QGIS knows the correct saved extent (in the project file and "Zoom Last"), but jumps to 0,0 on re-load.

Thoughts on what could be going on here?  Thanks!

Update:
I opened the same project file on another machine (Windows) and the extent behaved as you would expect.  My Mac install of QGIS seems to be the issue here.  It is on OSX Mavericks and so that might be at the root of this.

Update 2:
On opening a new dataset with QGIS (right click on shapefile -> open with QGIS), the map jumps to center on 0,0 with an option to "Zoom Last" back to the extent of the new data.  Behaves as above, recognizes the initial extent and then immediately zooms to 0,0.

Comment: It's not a solution, but a workaround would be to use a spatial bookmark: http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#spatial-bookmarks

Comment: Thanks Dan C - I am using bookmarks in the map, but on open, the map still jumps to 0,0.  I can use the bookmark to get back to my desired extent or the "Zoom Last" button.